# Is there a why a userform _change procedureal event not be recursive?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have data in a textbox (call it info) on a userform that I would like the user to be able to change so I set up a info_change() subroutine. Problems are:

(1) as I load initial data into info.text from VBA, the info_change() subroutine is called.

(2) when I go into the info field to change the value INSIDE the info field, it call the info_change() subroutine again and continues to call the routine until the last entry I put in info field = value in info field before changing in (seems recursive)

Any thoughts? Maybe instead of calling it info_change(), call it another procedural event?

Thanks, Marty

Comment: If your box is named ```info``` then ```info_change()``` is an event procedure and will be called when the value in ```info``` is changed.

Comment: `Application.Enableevents` doesn't work on userform controls. You need to create your own flag variable (usually a boolean) and then amend all your event codes so that their first line checks the variable and simply exits if true. You can then set the variable to true whenever you need to 'disable' events and back to False again afterwards.

Comment: Huh TIL, need to muck around with excel userforms more I guess.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy example using `_AfterUpdate` event**

Instead of reacting each time a single part of the info textbox got changed by the control's `_Change` event, it's more efficient to use the `_AfterUpdate` event pausing till you changed to another control (btw could be easily augmented by a `CommandButton` procedure).

In order to prevent unnecessary calls a comparison is made between old and current info text using a **type** definition in the code module's declaration head. Furthermore I added a boolean IsTest variable to this definition to allow a test display of changes made triggering some other stuff in code (see b).

Additional hint: there's *no recursion*, the `Change` event or `AfterUpdate` event are only firing as reaction to each single change or update, i.e. making no difference if triggered via `Userform_Initialize` settings or an eventual user input, however the condition check prevents the Init from getting active.

**Declaration head of Userform code module**

```
Option Explicit         ' declaration head of code module

'User defined type
Private Type TThis
    cnt    As Long
    oldTxt As String
    IsTest As Boolean
End Type
Dim this As TThis
```

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'[1]assign text to Info-Control
    Me.TextBox1.Text = "bla bla"
'[2]remember text
    this.oldTxt = Me.TextBox1.Text
'[3]optional choice of test modus
    this.IsTest = True
    If this.IsTest Then Debug.Print " #", "Change history", "(new) text" & vbNewLine; 0, Now, this.oldTxt
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'~> Example call
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    check Me.TextBox1
End Sub

Sub check(myTextbox As MSForms.TextBox)
' Purp.: compare current text with old text
If this.oldTxt <> myTextbox.Text Then
    'a) optional test display
        If this.IsTest Then this.cnt = this.cnt + 1: Debug.Print this.cnt, Now, myTextbox.Text
    'b) do other stuff
    '   ...

    'c) remember old text
        this.oldTxt = myTextbox.Text
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Martin-Feinstein Posted above solution; consider to accept if you found it helpful by ticking the green checkmark just underneath the voting buttons :)